# Better approach to online builder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a windows forms application which needs customized dll files to be built and for that I am using an online builder using asp.net. I am in no way a asp.net expert not even near a beginner but this is what I have come up with so far:

[image: Project]

All the work is done by the Handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(context.Server.MapPath("D2.dll"));

        var ctor = assembly.MainModule.Types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName.Contains("ClassName") && t.Namespace.Contains("NameSpace"))
            .Methods.FirstOrDefault(m => m.FullName.Contains("ctor"));

        // Update Instructions
        ctor.Body.Instructions[1].Operand = context.Request["A"];
        ctor.Body.Instructions[4].Operand = context.Request["GM"];
        ctor.Body.Instructions[7].Operand = context.Request["GI"];
        ctor.Body.Instructions[10].Operand = context.Request["U"];
        ctor.Body.Instructions[13].Operand = context.Request["CT"];
        ctor.Body.Instructions[16].Operand = context.Request["MT"];
        ctor.Body.Instructions[19].Operand = context.Request["D"];

        // Optimize the Body - Required to allow proper build
        ctor.Body.OptimizeMacros();
        ctor.Body.SimplifyMacros();

        // Write the Assembly to Stream so it can be converted to Byte[]
        var memstream = new MemoryStream();
        assembly.Write(memstream);

        // Clear existing response.
        context.Response.Clear();

        // Write new response.
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Build.dll");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", memstream.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(memstream.ToArray());
    }
```

Currently using this approach/model I have a lot of problems mainly debugging and fixing errors.

I want to improve on this but due to my lack of knowledge in web applications I see no clear path to choose. I have looked at SignalR and it seems like a better approach as it can provide features such as Progress Responses from the server. But still I am confused.

Comment: What exactly are the kind of problems you are having?

Comment: No problems. It's all working. I am asking for a better alternative.

Comment: You mention you're having a lot of issues in debugging, can you elaborate?

Comment: If something breaks down on the server end I have to publish a debug build and then try to work out what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

This looks good to me. A nice use of space, Everything is very clear and easy to read, just a couple of problems:

**Magic Numbers / Strings**

You have a few of these dotted about, a couple of examples:

`ctor.Body.Instructions[1].Operand = context.Request["A"];`

I have no idea what A signifies here, nor why it should be the first instruction's operand. Swap `A` with a const that gives that string a name describing its purpose. You can probably do the same for `1` in this scenario too, unless `A`'s purpose is only `FirstInstructionOperandCode` or something similar.

**Commenting**

Your comments don't add anything to your code. A lot of them just describe what you're doing, which any maintenance programmer can work out by reading the actual code. Instead you should use your comments to describe *why* you're doing something, particularly if it breaks from the expected norms.

The most egregious example is this:

```
// Clear existing response.
context.Response.Clear();
```

**Structure**

The Write New Response section could be refactored out into a separate method, but unless you're writing these responses elsewhere, it's probably not going to give you any significant gains.